# FFMPEG - zoom an overlaid PNG in the centre of a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, zoom

I want to show an image in the center of an HD video frame and then grow it, but keeping it centered.  My test program:

```
@call ffmpeg -y ^
  -loop 1 -i "image.png" -ss 0 -t 10 ^
  -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1920x1080 [bg]; [0] scale=300x300,zoompan=z=zoom+(0.1/30) [fg]; [bg][fg] overlay=x=(1920-w)/2:y=(1080-h)/2:shortest=1 " ^
  "out.mp4"
```

shows stuff zooming, but not how I wanted.  I was intending that the test program show the image doubling in size over the 10-second duration. What is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this using scale filter in ffmpeg 4.3 or recent git build.

`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i "image.png" -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1920x1080 [bg]; [0] scale=w=iw+iw*n/250:h=-1:eval=frame [fg]; [bg][fg] overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" -ss 0 -t 10 "out.mp4"`

Comment: OK, I'm getting `Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'n/250)'`. I assume that's because I have 4.2.3 (hopefully).  Stand by...

Comment: Perfect with 4.3.  I always wondered why `scale` couldn't accept timing parameters.  Many thanks.